# Group Concat Or Something Else? Mysql Query Taking So Long

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my Tables structures:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alljobs`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alljobs`
(
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Department` varchar(50) NULL,
    `SourceSite` varchar(50) NULL,
    `Title` varchar(255) NULL,
    `Description` text NULL,
    `JobType` varchar(50) NULL,
    `MainCategory` varchar(100) NULL,
    `SubCategory` varchar(100) NULL,
    `Url` varchar(255) NULL,
    `TimeOfCreation` varchar(50) NULL,
    `UnixTime` varchar(25) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `Department` (`Department`),
    KEY `SourceSite` (`SourceSite`),
    KEY `Title` (`Title`),
    KEY `MainCategory` (`MainCategory`),
    KEY `SubCategory` (`SubCategory`),
    KEY `UnixTime` (`UnixTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='To Hold All Job Information';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `joblocations`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joblocations`
(
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `jobId` varchar(25) NULL,
    `Location` varchar(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `jobId` (`jobId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='To Hold Job Locations';
```

this is the query i am trying:

(it is basically the query if user doesn't apply any filter on the search page)

```
Select j.Department, j.SourceSite, j.Title, j.Url,
Group_Concat(l.Location Separator '||') As Locations
From alljobs as j
Left Outer Join joblocations as l On l.jobId = j.ID
Group By j.ID
Order By j.Title
Limit 25 Offset 0;
```

**But it's taking 4-5 minutes to execute the query on phpMyadmin and on php it's just timing out..**

there is only 30-40k data in both tables.

but if the user apply any search filter and execute it, **it's takes less than a second** (as per phpMyAdmin results saying):

```
Select j.Department, j.SourceSite, j.Title, j.Url,
Group_Concat(l.Location Separator '||') As Locations
From alljobs as j
Left Outer Join joblocations as l On l.jobId = j.ID
Where Department In ('Healthcare', 'Food', 'Technology', 'Lifestyle')
And MainCategory Like '%Marketing%'And Location Like '%California%'
Group By j.ID
Order By j.Title
Limit 25 Offset 0 ;
```

so, i don't understand what i am doing wrong here? i just wanted to have first 25 rows of data and concat the locations on 2nd table (matched by job id) in to single column.

any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

best regards

Comment: always check with explain analyse what actually happens with the query

Comment: @nbk, i don't see any way to run explain analyze on phpMyAdmin :(

Comment: You can run the commands in any gui https://dbfiddle.uk/NB9eyn_b

Comment: @nbk thanks, but on phpMyAdmin when i tried only "explain" keyword before the query it works, but if i use "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" keywords, it throws an error :(

Comment: then post the result if the first and also which version you are actually running

Comment: If you write down your query properly, like you did with the table structures, your question will become a lot easier to read. It might help someone to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a real reason why your query should be so slow. However, since you group by `j.ID` and then order by `j.Title`, followed by a limit, the query has to process all data in the two tables before it can output the result. You only need 25 of the 30-40k rows from the `alljobs` table.

So let's rethink this. First write down the query for one table:

```
SELECT 
  j.Department, 
  j.SourceSite,
  j.Title,
  j.Url,
  <... Locations... >
FROM alljobs AS j
ORDER BY j.Title
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

This should be very quick, since `j.Title` is an index. The only problem left is, of course, that `Locations` doesn't work. We could write a subquery for this:

```
SELECT 
  j.Department, 
  j.SourceSite,
  j.Title,
  j.Url,
  (SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(l.Location SEPARATOR '||')
   FROM joblocations AS l 
   WHERE l.jobId = j.ID) AS Locations
FROM alljobs AS j 
ORDER BY j.Title
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

The query now has to execute this subquery 25 times. That's quite a lot but still a lot less than going through the whole table. What should make it reasonable quick is that `l.jobId` is an index.

The reason your query with the search filters is a lot quicker is because you already filter out a lot of rows in advance with those search filters. A smaller data set is just quicker. However, the data set might not be small for some search filters, making the query take a lot longer.

If you want to use a query with a subquery, as shown above, it should look something like:

```
SELECT 
  j.Department, 
  j.SourceSite,
  j.Title,
  j.Url,
  (SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(l.Location SEPARATOR '||')
   FROM joblocations AS l 
   WHERE l.jobId = j.ID) AS Locations
FROM alljobs AS j 
WHERE j.Department IN ('Healthcare', 'Food', 'Technology', 'Lifestyle')
      AND j.MainCategory LIKE '%Marketing%' 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT ID
                  FROM joblocations AS m 
                  WHERE m.jobId = j.ID
                        AND m.Location LIKE '%California%')
ORDER BY j.Title
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

I hope this works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i have updated my post/question as well, because i m confused i am using this (your) query pattern, will it work/return same result for my actual query (with search filter applied on locations (2nd table) as well)?

Comment: @SalmaBegum I could have a look at your second question, but can you give me feedback on my answer? 1. Does it work? 2. How long does it take? Remember, I cannot actually execute these queries on your data.

Comment: dear sir, yes it does works.. for no filtered data, but i don't know how to prepare the query for the filtered data (as per my 2nd query in post). Besides, if you want, i can give you my sql dump file?

Comment: @SalmaBegum: I added a query with filtering to my answer. Can you work with that?

Comment: please check the following link: https://imgur.com/a/X4prRRI this is the screenshot of your query and my query differences, and also when i export my query as josn file, it only have 25 objects/rows of data but your query returns 786 objects/rows of data!!

al though of course, thanks a lot for your time and support..

Comment: @SalmaBegum Yes, I was afraid of something like this. The original query, without filtering, is using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, whereas the one with filtering doesn't really, even though it uses the same JOIN. That's because the WHERE part uses fields from both tables. My query still does a real LEFT OUTER JOIN. It's basically the difference between a "LEFT OUTER JOIN" and a "SEMI JOIN" in [this poster](https://stevestedman.com/2015/03/mysql-join-types-poster/).

Comment: I have rewrite the query using two subqueries. This turns my LEFT OUTER JOIN into a SEMI JOIN. The first subquery is used to create the "locations" in the output and the second subquery is used to create the SEMI JOIN using the location filter. Again, I do this without testing it on real data, so there's always a change it doesn't work.

Comment: please do pardon me, but i don't think running multiple sub-quires is the only solution. I think there is better way either using no sub-queries or at least only one sub queries.

Comment: @SalmaBegum: Yes, of course. Your own query uses no subqueries. However, let us not forget the original problem you laid out in your question: Why is one query slow, and the other not. Do you understand why this happens now?